# Is it possible to unmarshal json string representing a byte array within a struct?

Tags: json, go

I have an API that returns a JSON object with a field containing a byte array (simplified):

```
{
    "value": "[208,188,149,77,179,245,29,184]"
}
```

I can unmarshal a `string` to a `[]byte` just fine:

```
var test = make([]byte,0)

testData := []byte("[208,188,149,77,179,245,29,184]")

_ = json.Unmarshal(testData, &test)

fmt.Println(len(test)) // output: 8
```

However, when I try to unmarshal this via a `struct`, it doesn't:

```
type Test struct {
    Value []byte `json:"value"`
}

testData := []byte(`
    {
        "value": "[208,188,149,77,179,245,29,184]"
    }
`)

var test = Test{}
err := json.Unmarshal(testData, &test)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err) // output: illegal base64 data at input byte 0
}
```

I get an error:

```
illegal base64 data at input byte 0
```

Is there anything I can do besides using `json.RawMessage` and manually unmarshalling this field separately?

Thanks.

Comment: That is a ridiculous format of api response.   If arbitrary binary data needs to be encoded in json, a base 64 encoded string is the logical and standard way.

Comment: It's just a JSON string. If you want to treat the contents of that string as JSON, you'll need to unmarshal the value in that field after you unmarshal the outer struct.

Comment: @DanielFarrell: I completely agree, but sadly have no control over the API in use.

Comment: As @Adrian wrote: in your first example you unmarshal a JSON array, while in your 2nd example it's a JSON string, not an array. Change `Test.Value` to `string`, and do a second unmarshal, this time into a `[]byte`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is because the Unmarshaller is encountering an illegal value at the index 0, i.e., `"`. So this would work if your `json` string had the byte array unqouted because that's the correct syntax.

```
    {
        "value": [208,188,149,77,179,245,29,184]
    }
```

If you have no control over the response you get from the api one thing you can do is to write your own `CustomMarshalJSON`. You can find the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/NgaRx7OiwnN). This will make your code cleaner and you wouldn't have to worry about unmarshalling the rawvalue every time you receive this kind of json value.

Comment: Can the folks downvoting the answer be considerate enough to mention what's wrong with it please? We are all trying to learn here.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and is the cleanest approach I've seen.  Don't worry about the downvotes.  You helped me out with not only why my example wasn't working, a clean solution, and also an example.  Thank you!  And yes, still learning :)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments by @icza and @DanielFarrell, this does work:

```
type Test struct {
    RawValue string `json:"value"`
    Value []byte `json:"-"`
}

testData := []byte(`
    {
        "value": "[208,188,149,77,179,245,29,184]"
    }
`)

var test = Test{}
err := json.Unmarshal(testData, &test)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}

value := make([]byte, 0)
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(test.RawValue), &value)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}

// assign the value to the original struct
test.Value = value

fmt.Println(len(test.Value)) // output: 8
```